# How does time dilation from a large body fall off?

Tags: black-hole, planet, distances, time-dilation

A magnetic fields generally fall off as 1 / r^3 rather than 1 / r^2 for gravity.
How does time dilation fall off from a large body?

Where would the gravity and magnetic field line be in this chart provided from comments?

[image]

Comment: You are expected to do some research before asking questions on Stack Exchange sites. Steve has answered your question, but also see https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Orbit_times.svg

Comment: @PM2Ring sorry I tried and prefer the SE format, but your link helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is given on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#Outside_a_non-rotating_sphere)
$$t_{0}=t_{f}{\sqrt {1-{\frac {2GM}{rc^{2}}}}}=t_{f}{\sqrt {1-{\frac {r_{s}}{r}}}}$$

Here $t_0$ is the time measured by clock distance $r$ from an object whose Schwarzschild radius is $r_s$ as calculated by a distant observer at rest whose clock measures $t_f$.

This is however, dependent on how the distant observer decides which ticks of your clock occur at the same time as which ticks of theirs, for which there are a number of perfectly reasonably choices, each of which gives a distinct answer. This formula is for what are called Schwarzschild coordinates, but there are other coordinate frames. Each one forces the distant observer to do a different calculation based on when they receive light signals from the close-in clocks ticks, in order to decide  at what time the tick happened.

Comment: updated question.